# Netty- cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe

Tags: java, netty, java-11

When I upgraded the Java from 8 to 11, I got an error from Netty about the `"jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe"`, the details are below:

I knew it is a debug level message, and I can change the level of the log to ignore it. But I'm not sure if there would be other problems - such as performance - when I ignore it. Does anyone know the best solution to this?

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @84b8f0f
    at jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6.run(PlatformDependent0.java:334) ~[netty-all-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:325) ~[netty-all-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:214) ~[netty-all-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:82) ~[netty-all-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator.<clinit>(UnpooledByteBufAllocator.java:37) ~[netty-all-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.Unpooled.<clinit>(Unpooled.java:73) ~[netty-all-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.base.connector.supplier.DelimiterDecoderSupplier.getDelimiter(DelimiterDecoderSupplier.java:41) ~[classes/:?]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.base.connector.supplier.DelimiterDecoderSupplier.<init>(DelimiterDecoderSupplier.java:26) ~[classes/:?]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.base.connector.supplier.DelimiterDecoderSupplier.<init>(DelimiterDecoderSupplier.java:20) ~[classes/:?]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.base.connector.supplier.CommonChannelHandlerSupplier.<init>(CommonChannelHandlerSupplier.java:37) ~[classes/:?]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.base.connector.supplier.CommonChannelHandlerSupplier.<init>(CommonChannelHandlerSupplier.java:25) ~[classes/:?]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.base.connector.TcpClientConnector.start(TcpClientConnector.java:39) ~[classes/:?]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.bootstrap.FrameworkLauncher.lambda$start$0(FrameworkLauncher.java:61) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) [?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) [?:?]
    at wedo.stream3.framework.bootstrap.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:58) [classes/:?]
    at org.stream3.prototype.mfc.App.launchFramework(App.java:58) [classes/:?]
    at org.stream3.prototype.mfc.App.main(App.java:41) [classes/:?]
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To allow netty to access the class, start java with the following option:

```
--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This opens the package `jdk.internal.misc` in module `java.base` to the unamed module.

See also the documentation for the [java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html), and this [intro to the Java module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) in general.

EDIT: For Netty to use its direct buffer optimizations, you also need to set

```
-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true
```

There are a number of Netty issues on this subject, see e.g. [netty/issues/7769](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7769)

Comment: But there still has  another message left:

`09:10:28.902 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable`
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled`

Is there any method to solve this ?

Comment: There is an issue on the netty github about that problem: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7817

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want to know does this parameter affect the performance ?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I notice that your netty version is from April. It could be worth a try to upgrade to the most recent version to see if the problem has been fixed: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all/4.1.41.Final

Comment: How do you pass these options to run `mvn test`?

Comment: You can use `<argLine>` in the configuration to maven-surefire-plugin in your pom.xml. For exampe (sorry for bad formatting): `<configuration><argLine>--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine></configuration>`

Answer (score 21):

When running Netty on Java 11, add these VM options to enable performance optimizations:

```
--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true
```

Then, to know when deep reflection is used, you may add:

```
--illegal-access=warn
```

Answer (score 5):

As you said this is just an debug message and can be ignored. It basically tells you that Netty can not make use of "all optimisations" because it can not access a class. If you want you can open up the access level via command line flags when starting your application tho.

Comment: Is this optimization something one would want to enable by default? Is this mentioned in some official guide, for instance?

Answer (score 3):

Netty requires access, to a jdk module, so to allow access you need to add a jvm argument when starting your application.

```
--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Additionally if you want to disable "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled....." warning stacktrace, you can also include:

```
-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true
```

If you are using gradle, you can add these on your build.gradle as follows:

```
   distributions {
        applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["--add-opens",
                                     "java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED", "-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true"]
        mainClassName = 'cl.domain.ServerLauncher'
        archivesBaseName = 'your-service'
        version = 'latest'
        main {
            baseName = 'your-service'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, using the latest version of `io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.53.0` , I found that the following is what you need (**not** the same flag names as above), running on Java 11.

```
-Dio.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true
--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/PlatformDependent0.java#L979) `io.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible` is no longer the property being checked.